# C2039 :'E' is not a member of "Node" error

Tags: c++

E is a member in the Node structure but I still get the C2039 error? here is my code :

```
#include "datastructures.h" //datastructures.cpp//
#include "utility.h"
#include "Functions.h"

bool enqueue(Queue &Q, enemy e){
    Node *dptr = new Node;
    if (dptr == NULL){
        return false;
        dptr->E  = e;    //C2039 here//
        if (Q.rear == NULL){
            Q.rear = Q.head = dptr;
            return true;
        }
        dptr->next = NULL;
        Q.rear = dptr;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

sorry I forgot to give the structure definition

```
struct Node{
    enemy E;
    Node *next;
};

struct enemy{
    //starting x,y
    int ID;
    int T;
    int Region;
    int Distance;
    float Health;
    int Type;
    int Pr;
    int P;
};
```

Comment: That line will never get reached due to the return false.

Comment: well? does Node have a data member called `E`?

Comment: Apparently, the compiler doesn't think so.  Can we see the declaration of `Node`, so we can mediate the dispute?

Comment: Does it also complain about `next` not being a member?

Comment: @JoeEhab12 Is there a cost involved in naming variables with more than one letter?  `E` is not descriptive at all.

Comment: @JamesCurran No it doesnt

Comment: You most likely are only quoting the error but not the warnings you also got.

Comment: Given that enemy is undefined when referencing it, I still think you are not giving us the complete picture here.

Comment: @Till well the solution is about 4 cpp files and 3 header files 
It's a bit long do you want me to post all of those?

Comment: Please check the FAQ on how to ask a self contained question.

Comment: @JoeEhab12: No, don't post it all. Post enough to reproduce the error. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `enemy` before `Node`, since `Node` has a member of that type, and the type of a member must be complete when it's declared.

Comment: enemy is defined in a header file "utility.h"
and so is Node in "datastructures.h" and both header files are included in the main cpp and "utility.h" is included before "datastructures.h"

Comment: @JoeEhab12  - But the code you have shows us `datastructures.h` being included before `utility.h`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry I dont post the whole code as its too long but in the main program "utility.h" is defined before "datastructures.h"

Comment: @JoeEhab12: Try to reduce the code to a small test case that still exhibits the problem. Then we can see exactly what's wrong, rather than trying to guess how your posted code fragments relate to what you're actually compiling.

Comment: @JoeEhab12 - Why are you bringing up the `main` program?   What does that have to do with the code you posted in your question?  The order of declaration is *highly* important -- if you just throw together some #includes in any old order and post that as a question, that wastes a lot of time in getting to the issue.

Comment: @JoeEhab12 - No Error: http://ideone.com/QyzYQl  Big Error: http://ideone.com/CQxBSk  Note the error message: `prog.cpp:23:11: error: ‘struct Node’ has no member named ‘E’ dptr->E = e;`  Looks familiar?

Answer (score 0):

When is comes to using a struct in another struct, you must first declare the struct that is contained in the other struct. In this case, the struct enemy which is a member of struct Node must be declare above struct Node. This enables struct Node to know what the struct enemy is about or all its members.

```
struct enemy{
    //starting x,y
    int ID;
    int T;
    int Region;
    int Distance;
    float Health;
    int Type;
    int Pr;
    int P;
};

struct Node{
    enemy E; //struct enemy is defined before used here
    Node *next;
};
```